# Why isn't Transmission working?

Tags: firewall, downloads, bittorrent, transmission

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu and Transmission.

According to Transmission, the file I am downloading has 0 peers and is idle, even though there are a few peers seeding it.

Here's a batch of error messages from Transmission's log:

```
> Could not connect to tracker. Tracker gave HTTP response code 503, 504
```

This is the firewall's status:

```
> To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
51413/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
51413/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere
51413/tcp                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
51413/udp                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
51413/tcp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
51413/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
25,53,80,110,443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
53/udp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
67,68/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
5050/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere
51413/tcp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
51413/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
25,53,80,110,443/tcp       ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
53/udp                     ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
67,68/udp                  ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
5050/tcp                   ALLOW OUT   Anywhere (v6)
```

Also, Transmission says that port `51413` is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running `sudo ufw allow out 6969/tcp` fixed my problem.

By opening port 6969(TCP) you allow the torrent software to communicate with the tracker.

Comment: It is nice you got Transmission working but it would also be nice that you explain what that command does so others can take advantage of your finding as well.

Comment: Ok. By opening port 6969(TCP) you allow the torrent software to communicate with the tracker.

Answer (score 3):

`503 Service Unavailable` and `504 Gateway Timeout` are tracker server responses.

Transmission did connect to the tracker but it failed to respond correctly. It's either overloaded or down. Try another tracker or torrent and see if it helps.

See [List of HTTP status codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes).

Comment: Thanks. I tried this torrent(http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.10/ubuntu-11.10-alternate-amd64.iso.torrent). Transmission still says that it's idle and has 0 peers. And the message log reads, "Could not connect to tracker.".

Comment: Edit: Here's the firewall log:

Feb 15 20:07:21 ubuntu kernel: [ 4200.736106] [UFW BLOCK] IN= OUT=ppp0 SRC=my ip DST=91.189.90.143 LEN=60 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=4917 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=33948 DPT=6969 WINDOW=4344 RES=0x00 SYN URGP=0

Comment: There are two trackers for this torrent: `http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce` and 
`http://ipv6.torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce` . First one works fine - second errors. Try adding first tracker in torrent properties

Comment: Both trackers were already added in the torrent file. Still nothing.